# Problem with making an index

Tags: indexing, incompatibility, amsart, makeidx

I have a Latex document that I compiles perfectly. I wanted to add an index to the document and since it is Latex I used the commands

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
```

added my `\index` commands and then went to compile it again. This time I got the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \see already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Beginn of the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{eucal} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex
\begin{document} 
... 
\begin{abstract} 
  {What follows is my proposal/request for research/education leave for the Spring semester (6 month leave at full salary) 2016.} 
\end{abstract} 
\maketitle
\printindex 
\section{Overview}\label{S:Introduction}\index{Introduction} 
...
```

Comment: Oops ... it printed the following line as being in error l.41 \newcommand*\see[2]{\emph{\seename} #1}. This error is in the  makeidx.sty file. I am confused.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with a complete minimal example which shows the error? The information you give er not enough. The following compiles fine: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\index{foo}
\end{document}`

Comment: the documentation for the ams document classes says explicitly that the facilities of `makeindex` are provided *in the document class*.  there are a few other idiosyncrasies, but mainly, don't specify `\usepackage{makeidx}` and if you really want a "see" reference, use `\seeonly`.  (long story, which i'll forgo here.)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you Barbara!!!!

Comment: The problem is solved. Barbara hit it on the head. I didn't realize that makeidx is already embedded in Latex. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @tmwitten -- not embedded in *latex*, but provided in the *ams document classes*.  (there's a difference.  it's *not*, for example, in `article`.  not all document classes are "created equal".)

Answer (score 9):

the documentation for the **ams document classes** (`amsart`, `amsbook`
and `amsproc`) says explicitly that the facilities of `makeindex`
are provided in the document class.  so don't put `\usepackage{makeidx}`
in the preamble.

there are a few idiosyncrasies, the main one being that if you really want
a "*see*" reference, use `\seeonly`.  (for historical reasons, and really a misfeature, `\see` produces "*see also*", but it's too late to change now,
as it would affect too many published documents.)

Comment: Can you link to the documentation for the AMS document classes where it says that?

Comment: I found it:  [AMS Author Handbook:  Journal Classes (September 2017)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/amscls-doc/Author_Handbook_Journals.pdf)  Subsection 3.2 page 10:  "`makeidx` facilities are already in AMS document classes."